# Find a function in the style of $-\tanh(x)$ with a few conditions

Tags: exponential-function

I'm searching for a function that looks somewhat like a shifted

$-\tanh(x)$-function

Through some searching and playing with Wolfram Alpha I managed to shift it in the x-direction, which is partly what I want. Now the plot looks like [that](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-tanh(x-1)) and the function like that:

$-\tanh(x-t)$

I also found out that there is an (at least similar) exponential form of this, perhaps it might help anybody: $-\frac{(e^{x-2t}-e^{-x})}{(e^{x-2t}+e^{-x})}$ What I can't figure out at the moment is how to make the function fulfil the following requirements:

**Edited requirements, sorry!**

- $f(0) \approx 1$
- "stretch" and "compress" the function in x-direction. What I try to reach is a function with a variable $t$ that also fulfils the following conditions:

  - $f(t)=0$
  - $f(2t)\approx-1$

By $\approx$ I mean something near $1$ and $-1$. Perhaps as near as $0.9$ or even as near as I want it to be?

I hope I made myself clear, it's a long time since I actually used mathematics...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of $-\tanh(x-t)$, try $-\tanh(c(x-t))$ for $c > 1$. That will cause the function to get close to $-1$ faster.

Comment: That's the right direction! Is there a way I can tie $f(0) = 0.9$?

Comment: Ok, I found something with some more WolframAlpha try&error: I can choose $c=\frac{\tanh^{-1}(0.9)}{t}$! Yeah!